# С++ Универсальный способ вызвать любую функцию дважды

Tags: c++

Проблема состоит в следующем: мне необходимо вызвать функцию саму себя ещё раз в случае, если она вернёт `false`.

Казалось бы, всё очень просто. Но таких функций очень много, и аргументы они принимают разные.

В примере кода сравнивается какой-то конечный результат и в случае необходимости эта функция вызывается ещё один раз.

Проблема в том, что в каждой функции писать это сравнение сложно, долго и опасно.

> Можно ли упростить эту задачу с помощью какого-нибудь `define` или универсальной функции, которая бы вызывала переданную функцию не больше двух раз?

Define, например, бы вставлял название функции и её аргументы (как я себе представляю)

```
bool doSmth(int val)
{
    if (res == false) {
        static thread_local bool called = false;
        if (called) {
            called = false;
        }
        else {
            called = true;
            return doSmth(val);            
        }  
    }
    return res;
}
```

Было бы хорошо, если блок `if` заменить на какой-нибудь макрос или функцию, например:

```
bool doSmth(int val)
{
    bool res = compute(val);
    return CALL_FUNC_AGAIN_IF_FALSE(res);
}
```

В этом случае функция выполняется ещё один раз, затем возвращается результат независимо от того, `true` или `false`.

Comment: Мне кажется или это проблема XY? В идеальном случаем функция, которая была вызвана дважды с одними и теми же аргументами должна возвращать одинаковый результат. Понятно, что в реальном мире это сложно добиться, но следует держатся такой концепции.

Comment: Враппер шаблонный запилите и будет все ок

Comment: Ну, не совсем так. Это сетевое приложение, которое работает с БД. И есть ситуации, при которых функцию нужно вызвать ещё раз с теми аргументами и результат будет другим. Именно это мне и нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return called || doSmth(val);` или о чем?

```cpp
bool doSmth(int val, bool retry = true)
{
    return compute(val) || retry && doSmth(val, false);
}
```

?
Ну или что-нибудь вроде

```cpp
template<class F, class... Args> auto at_most_twice(F &&f, Args &&...args) {
    return std::invoke(f, args...) || std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

Class instance;
at_most_twice(&Class::method, instance, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что блок if нужно вставлять абсолютно во все функции, что сильно затрудняет написание кода. Мой вопрос в том, как вынести этот код в отдельную функцию?

Comment: Ваш вариант с at_most_twice мне нравится. Но как его вызвать для методов класса?

Comment: Гм, добавил. :-O

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, более простым решением будет переложить эту задачу на **вызывающий код**.

```
bool ff(const char *t) {
  puts(t);
  return t[0] == '2';
}

bool fff(const char *t, const char *s) {
  puts(t); puts(s);
  return t[0] == '2';
}

#define call2(f, ...) (f(__VA_ARGS__) || f(__VA_ARGS__))

int main()
{
  call2(ff, "123");
  call2(fff, "abc", "xxx");
  call2(fff, "22", "333");
}
```

Подробнее о макросах с переменым числом аргументов можно прочесть [тут](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Вызываем

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ t.cpp -O3
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
123
123
abc
xxx
abc
xxx
22
333
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Это?